# Avoid expanding macro used inside another macro

Tags: c++

I'm creating a new macro which uses another macro inside of it. But the nested macro is from a third-party library so it won't compile if it is expanded. How can I avoid the expanding and use that nested macro as a function call?

Code example:

```
#define MY_MACRO(severity, data) \
  LOG(severity) << data;
```

call site:

```
MY_MACRO(ERROR, "test_data")
```

Comment: try changing `LOG` to `(LOG)` .  To get better answers post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You don't want to expand `LOG` or `LOG(level)` or `data` or `level` or `some_function()`?

Comment: @KamilCuk LOG() is actually the glog macro that I'm using. The problem with expanding LOG is that it won't compile and complains "use of undeclared identifier 'COMPACT_GOOGLE_LOG_serverity'"

Comment: @M.M updated code snippet

Comment: How is undeclared identifier related to macro expansion? You wan't LOG not to expand, so `#undef` it, right? How to replicate the behavior? Please provide a minimal, reproducible example? Even a short search in the net resulted in [this](https://github.com/TokTok/jvm-toxcore-c/blob/master/cpp/src/util/logging.h#L29). It is still unclear what you want to do. Please include the macro declaration of `LOG()` and provide minmal reproducible example. Why would you want not to expand `LOG()`? Isn't your goal to expand it properly with the `severity` word substituted for `ERROR`?

Comment: @KamilCuk please see my updated sample code. The compiler gives me ""use of undeclared identifier 'COMPACT_GOOGLE_LOG_serverity'" error because `glog/include/glog/logging.h:564:23: note: expanded from macro 'LOG'
#define LOG(severity) COMPACT_GOOGLE_LOG_ ## severity.stream()
                      ^
<scratch space>:77:1: note: expanded from here
COMPACT_GOOGLE_LOG_serverity`

Comment: @KamilCuk macro declaration is from glog. it's kind of weird that I'm able to use `LOG(ERROR) << "error msg"` in a function in the same file, but when using it inside of the macro, it gives me that compiler error.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion from my first comment?  BTW a more robust option would be to not use the identifier `LOG` in your program at all (other than when you intentionally mean the macro from this other library)

Comment: I just tried replacing word "severity" with "level" then it see to work! I guess some conflict with LOG(severity) macro from glog?

Comment: @M.M I did try your suggestion from first comment but it does not work. Now this problem is resolved. Thank you very much for discussing the problem and the solutions!